# Django password reset email subject

Tags: python, django

I have successfully added my own custom HTML templates for the password reset pages in Django and it's all working nicely. The only bit I can't work out it how to include my own email subject.

The default is "Password reset on [my site name]" and I can obviously change the site name in admin but does anyone know how to override the whole subject line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Development Version**

Just create new file `registration/password_reset_subject.txt` in your templates dir. This will override default django subject

See https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/templates/registration/password_reset_subject.txt

and https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py line 150

**In Django 1.3**

if you use internalization just add in `.po` file

```
#: forms.py:143
#, python-format
msgid "Password reset on %s"
msgstr "YOUR SUBJECT HERE %s"
```

if not folow next steps

in root urls.py

```
# change to your custom view
(r'^password_reset/$', 'your_app.views.password_reset'),
```

in your your_app/views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import password_reset as django_password_reset
from .forms import CustomPasswordResetForm

# reuse Django view, but change form
def password_reset(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['password_reset_form'] = CustomPasswordResetForm
    django_password_reset(*args, **kwargs):
```

rewrite save method in your your_app/forms.py (I know it not DRY but should work :)

```
class CustomPasswordResetForm(PasswordResetForm):
    def save(self, domain_override=None, email_template_name='registration/password_reset_email.html',
         use_https=False, token_generator=default_token_generator, request=None):
        from django.core.mail import send_mail
        for user in self.users_cache:
            if not domain_override:
                current_site = get_current_site(request)
                site_name = current_site.name
                domain = current_site.domain
            else:
                 site_name = domain = domain_override
            t = loader.get_template(email_template_name)
            c = {
            'email': user.email,
            'domain': domain,
            'site_name': site_name,
            'uid': int_to_base36(user.id),
            'user': user,
            'token': token_generator.make_token(user),
            'protocol': use_https and 'https' or 'http',
            }
            send_mail(_("YOUR SUBJECT HERE %s") % site_name,
                t.render(Context(c)), None, [user.email])
```

Comment: This makes sense, is there anything I need to do to make it override the default? I've put password_reset_subject.txt in the same /registration/ dir as the rest of the password reset templates but it's still using the default subject.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, Giv I was a bit wrong. Path depends on TEMPLATE_DIRS setting. If template will be placed in /<one_of_your_TEMPLATE_DIRS>/auth/registration/ should works

Comment: Thanks Alexey but I'm still not able to make this work. Does this work with Django 1.3.0? Because I just looked at forms.py in contrib directory and there's no mention of password_reset_subject.txt - the PasswordResetForm class' save() method doesn't specify password_reset_subject.txt - the subject is hard-coded. Any ideas how I can override this?

Comment: I've just updated the answer. This code is not tested, but hope you catch the idea

Comment: I get the following error:
Exception Value: 
'CustomPasswordResetForm' object has no attribute 'users_cache'

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed about 8 months ago but the change doesn't seem to have made merged into 1.3.1. See:
https://github.com/django/django/commits/master/django/contrib/auth/templates

Answer (score 0):

The [**`PasswordResetForm`**](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L107) sends the email based on your `contrib.sites`. It gets the domain name to use and passes it to the html template at `registration/password_reset_email.html`

use admin or django shell to change the `site`

in shell you can do this by doing:

```
>>> from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
>>> my_site = Site(domain='your_domain.com', name='Your Domain')
>>> my_site.save()
>>> print my_site.id
2
>>>
```

in your settings.py:

```
SITE_ID = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it doesn't answer my question. I've mentioned I know how to change the contrib.sites value but the subject will still say "Password reset on..." - I would like to know how to change the entire subject to say "Change your password".