# Django override password_reset_subject.txt does not change subject

Tags: python, django, django-2.1

I created `registration/password_reset_subject.txt` to change the subject of my password reset email as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8457769/9177173). However, it does not take effect.

The email subject remains `Subject: Password reset on 127.0.0.1:8000`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer myself.

I got it to work by placing `registration/password_reset_subject.txt` in a global template folder.

It is also possible to place `registration/password_reset_subject.txt` in the template folder of a submodule. 
However, for this to work the module must come before `'django.contrib.auth'` in the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Right you are, re-arranging the 'django.contrib.auth' in INSTALLED_APPS to come after 'my_apps' fixes this issue.